# Recommended git workflow

Tags: git

I would like to make a pull request per feature. But I'm having problem with the workflow.

For example, I worked on a feature in branch `feature1`, made a pull request and while I wait for that pull request to be approve I want to start working on another feature.

In `feature2` I would like to have the code from `feature1`, what is the best approach for this?

I used to make another branch from `feature1`, but then when I make a pull request of `feature2` to `master` I have all the changes from `feature1` and `feature2`.

How people do this?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, branching from `feature1` to start `feature2` is probably the best idea.  So ideally you should enforce that `feature1` gets merged first, before `feature2`.  If you categorically can't enforce this order, then it might imply that you should have started work on `feature2` before `feature1`, that is, you should have switched the branches.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little more on what has already been said: feature2 can be on top of feature1, the only thing is that you have to be careful when moving the branch around so *not* to automatically include stuff from feature1..... this is so because there might be different situations that can make it break if you are not careful. For example: Feature1 gets to be merged..... but squashed. Then the revisions that feature2 is on aren't valid anymore....  same thing if feature1 is rebased..... or reworked completely.... in all those cases you will have to be careful to *not* include the revisions from feature1 when you move feature2 around.

The easiest way to handle this is by rebasing feature2 but only what really makes it up:

```
git rebase --onto anywhere feature2~4 feature2
```

That is assuming feature2 is made up of 4 straight revisions. So, all in all, it's ok.... just be careful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is not to do so.

As long as there is some other `featureX` which does not require code from `feature1`, I would start with `featureX` instead of `feature2`.

During code review there might be change-requests which affect the code you need for `feature2`.

If waiting for `feature1` to be merged is not realistic, (review will take too long and there are no other features to start with), then `feature2` can be branched out of `feature1`. However, if `feature1` is squashed into `master` you'll need to do some rebasing, or branch out of master again and cherry-pick the work specific to feature2 from the original `feature2` branch into the new `feature2` branch.

Answer (score 0):

> In `feature2` I would like to have the code from `feature1`

You can’t. The "code from `feature1`" is the very code on which you are awaiting approval! If you are permitted to incorporate unapproved changes into *another* new branch, then what is the point of a PR and the whole approval process? You might as well be working alone and skip PR altogether.

Features, in your architecture, need to be *independent.* Conversely, if they are not independent, then you should not have submitted a PR prematurely; this should all have been one long branch.

Comment: Well.... let's agree to disagree. This can be done.... the only thing is that the Developer has to be _careful_ about moving their branch later on so _not_ to include feature1 stuff.... which can be easily done with `git rebase --onto anywhere feature1 feature2`

Comment: Good tip, thanks. I'm glad you added that as an answer (and I upvoted it).